# Style the Marker icon in Google Maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

My markers looks like:

```
<Marker
    key={id}
    position={{
            lat: business.branch?.address?.lat,
            lng: business.branch?.address?.lng,
           }}
    icon={{                     
        url: '/static/images/location markeRlightmode.svg', 
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
        }}
/>
```

Package Used: google-maps-react

By any chance, can I style the marker icon here? My icon currently is rectangular and I want to put border-radius css to the icon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi did you try anything like adding a class just to check

Comment: Marker doesn't take class or className so I can't add CSS using that.

Comment: I checked their source code and I could not find a class prop

Comment: Style your icons separately it should be easy since its a svg file. anyway it seems its not possible by css

Comment: Is there any way to pass the component for the marker icon?